# Tableau- How to work on sub set of data created from aggregated data

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

I want to implement subquery in tableau

```
select  count( distinct t.user_id ) from 
(SELECT user_id, max(created_at) as rt FROM sample_table group by user_id) t
where t.rt  <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY  and t.rt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

How can I get the output of this query using tableau... I don't want to create any views but I want to make use of `user_id` and `created_at` dimensions in tableau to get the above answer.

Basically how I will work on the subset of data in tableau.

Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated field called `max_created_at`:

```
{FIXED user_id: MAX(created_at)}
```

*Note: This will only work in Tableau 9.0 or above.*

Then you can simply:

1. Create a filter for the max_created_at field
2. Drag user_id to the text mark
3. Right click user_id
4. Select Measure/Count(Distinct).

[Click here for more information on Level of Detail Aggregations](http://vizpainter.com/my-favorite-tableau-9-0-feature/)